# Invariance of products of objects in a category

Tags: category-theory

I would like to know whether the following is false or not, since I can't really get a good grip on it.

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is any category and let $P$ be a product of two given objects $X$ and $Y$. Suppose $P'$ is an object such that $P' \cong P$. Is $P'$ also a product of $X$ and $Y$ then?

My first thinking is no, but I don't know how to prove it exactly.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you've already accepted an answer, but contrary to what the answer you accepted suggests, the actual answer to your question is in fact *yes*. The same is true of arbitrary limits (and colimits), but let's focus on products here.

Let $X \xleftarrow{\pi_1} P \xrightarrow{\pi_2} Y$ be a product diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ and suppose that $P \cong P'$. Let $u : P \to P'$ be the given isomorphism. It is easy to check that
$$X \xleftarrow{\pi_1 \circ u^{-1}} P' \xrightarrow{\pi_2 \circ u^{-1}} Y$$
is also a product diagram in $\mathcal{C}$. Indeed, given morphisms $f : A \to X$ and $g : A \to Y$, the unique morphism $A \to P'$ factoring through the new product projections is precisely $u \circ \langle f,g \rangle$, where $\langle f,g \rangle$ is the unique morphism $A \to P$ factoring through the old product projections.

More generally, given any diagram $d : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$ and any limit cone
$$(L, (\lambda_j : L \to d(j))_{j \in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{J})})$$
for $d$ in $\mathcal{C}$, if $L \cong L'$ via an isomorphism $u : L \to L'$ in $\mathcal{C}$, then
$$(L', (\lambda_j \circ u^{-1} : L' \to d(j))_{j \in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{J})})$$
is another limit cone for $d$ in $\mathcal{C}$, thus exhibiting $L'$ as a limit of $d$.